# Prove a solution curve is approaching 1 but never touches it

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Consider an ode, $$\begin{align*}
y'=f(y)
\end{align*}$$ where $f \in C^{\infty}$ . Suppose $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and $f(y)>0 , \forall y\in(0,1)$ . Let $y$ be a solution of this ode and have the initial value $y(0)=a\in(0,1)$. I want to show that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ , we have $y'(x)>0$ . (strictly increasing)

I don't know where should I start this question. Let's only consider the as $x$ increasing. Intuitively, I can draw the picture of the solution curve $y$, and it should be approaching $1$ as $x$ increases, but it never touches $1$. Also, intuively, since $f>0$ for $y\in (0,1)$ , $f(1)=0$ ,  and $f$ is continuous, for some neighborhood of $1$ , $f$ should be decreasing, so $y'$ will be decreasing as $y$ goes to $1$ . That is, $y$ increases smaller and smaller when it approaches $1$.

However, I can't rigorously show this. I tried to suppose there exists a $x_0$ such that $y(x_0)=1$ and derive a contradiction, but I failed.
Any help on this?  Thanks.

Comment: also, curve approaches $1$   at positive infinity, but $0$ at $-\infty.$ You should solve explicitly when $f(y) = y(1-y),$   ought to use partial fractions. And draw a graph  of that curve

Comment: @FShrike. I think it is right. The thing is the problem asks to prove $y'>0$ for all $x$. If $y=1$ for some $x=x_0$, then $y'=0$ at $x_0$, so $y$ is not strictly increasing on $R$.

Comment: Sorry, I misread $y’=f(y)$ as $y’=f(x)$ : )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f(0)=f(1)=0$ hence $0$ and $1$ are stationary points of the ode, i.e. the two constant functions $y(x)=0$ and $y(x)=1$ are solutions of the ode.

Therefore, by uniqueness of the solution given some initial condition, a solution which happens to take the value $0$ (resp. $1$) is equal everywhere to $0$ (resp. $1$). Hence our solution $y$ such that $y(0)=a\in(0,1)$ never takes these two values. By continuity, it always stays inside the interval $(0,1).$ So, $y'(x)=f(y(x))>0.$

Note moreover that since $y$ is increasing, it admits limits $$0\le\alpha=\lim_{x\to-\infty}y(x)<\lim_{x\to+\infty}y(x)=\beta\le1.$$
$\beta$ cannot be $<1$ because else we would have $\lim_{x\to+\infty}y'(x)=f(\beta)>0,$ which would prevent $\lim_{x\to+\infty}y(x)$ from being finite. Hence $\beta=1.$ Similarly, $\alpha=0.$